# JFolder::create: Path not in open_basedir paths Joomla error

Tags: joomla

I am unable to install new components, module, on my live site using Joomla.

I got to know from another post that the problem might be in configuration file which in my case i have:

```
    public $log_path = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pastrimi/logs';
    public $tmp_path = 'C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\pastrimi/tmp';
```

and I also tried this way with no luck unfortunately:

```
    public $log_path = './logs';
    public $tmp_path = './tmp';
```

and I made the permission to 777 for both folders

how would I make this showing on joomla system information writable these two folders?

Comment: found the issue... i had to make the full path for both variables

Answer (score 0):

You have a set already below path this is called global path.

**1)** First try with this details.

```
public $log_path = './logs';
public $tmp_path = './tmp';
```

If you still got the error then follow the second step

**2)** Open cpanel and goes to file manager
 Left side you will see like below if your directory path in root

```
/home/Directoryname/public_html/logs
/home/Directoryname/public_html/tmp
```

If your directory in subdomain then use

```
/home/Directoryname/public_html/sub domain name/logs
/home/Directoryname/public_html/sub domain name/tmp
```